# emulator devices target level 18 and level 8 only

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

why cant I create an emulator with Target android 4.3-api level 18 or atleast level 17 and why does the target only has level 18 and level 8 api when I have installed all api from 1.5-18 its all stated in SDK manager that it is installed

Comment: have you tried changing from mainfest file

Comment: my problem is I cant create a AVD with level 17 api or 18 in the target drop down I only have level 8 and level 18 api but when I choose level 18 the ok button is off/not clickable it says that I have not choose a target

Comment: yes post your manifest file.. have you update your SDK

Comment: For level 17, you have to install 4.2 under sdk manager

Comment: Navigate to the 'Platforms' folder in the SDK directory, and check to see what all folders are listed.

Comment: I am assuming that you have updated your sdk just now so..So try to create AVD after restarting eclipse..

Comment: please check this link so you can see what I mean http://imageshack.us/gal.php?id=sJSoktGn2tCn1OPKmg

Comment: my bad guys should have restarted eclipse first instead of panicking sorry after I restarted it was all there thank you shakeeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your ADT.

Go to: Android SDK Manager -> and update Android SDK Tools like this:

[image]

Comment: done it mate thank you for your time I just have to restart eclipse and it worked just fine but I still have a problem a pop up menu keeps popping out saying "no compatible target were found.do you wish to add a new android virtual device"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have updated your sdk,If not working then do it once again.

And now Open your manifest file and change the line here:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```